# How can I hyperlink figures and tables in LaTeX?

Tags: hyperref, packages

I can hyperlink references by `hyperref` package.
But I can not hyperlink figures and tables?
should I use any certain package for labeling ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `hyperref` should turn all cross-references to hyperlinks, can you create a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) where it doesn't?

Comment: Actually, hyperref only links to captions, not figures or tables.  If you don't have captions, use \hypertarget and \hyperlink.

Comment: Of course, `hyperref` can "hyperlink" figures and table. And stuff can be labeled without any package. Thus the question as it stands is pretty unclear. Usually a MWE helps a lot in clarifying. However nothing happened since three weeks, therefore I suggest to close the question with reason "unclear what is asked".

Answer (score 1):

I found this for my old problem (like yours). It can be for all: `\cite` and `\ref` (table, figure, citation)
So, put this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = red, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor   = blue %Colour of citations
}
```

Comment: This just sets colored links instead of colored rectangles and changes the default colors. I do not see any relation to "figures", "tables", "labeling".

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, I'm using it and it does for all: tables, figure, citation, link, everything.

Comment: It's ok, but I cannot see any relation to the question, except that `hyperref` is used.